# Automatic Vectorisation in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, polyline-creation, vectorization

Is there any method or tool/model for ArcGIS to draw automatic line based upon raster data values.

E.g i have a DEM and i want to automatically generate a line feature passing through all those pixels whose values is less than 1.

Comment: Contour? Slice and then feature to polygon with IsNull on the slice? Minimum spanning tree https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340165/minimum-spanning-tree ? It might help if you draw a picture of what you're after with what you've got. Do you have a spatial analyst and/or 3d analyst extension license? Most of the raster tools require spatial analyst extension.

Comment: Yes contours can generate lines. But to be specific i am looking for a way to generate automatic mosaic line for 2 DEMs, such that the mosaic line for two dem should pass through the minimum elevation difference of the two dems in overlapping region.

Comment: Oh, I see you're feathering a DEM. Just remember to include that in your citation. I've used a different approach of placing a line in the overlap area, generating a distance raster then with the inverse of the distance modify each DEM proportionately until at maximum distance the change is 0. The distance need not be very great, it could be as little as 100 pixels then you won't see the obvious gap. Considering you're looking for the minimum you could generate flow accumulation then use a focal mean to identify the lowest channel(s), that would get you fairly close.

Comment: @MichaelStimson  thankyou. I will try this approach and then I will share the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [ArcScan](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/what-is-arcscan-.htm) (the bolding is mine):

> ArcScan provides tools that allow you to convert scanned images into
> vector-based feature layers. The process of converting raster data to
> vector features is known as vectorization. **Vectorization can be
> performed** manually by interactively tracing raster cells or
> **automatically using the automatic mode**.